# C2QB - OAUTH popup does not close, the application appears in the popup

Tags: oauth, popup, intuit-partner-platform

In my application
1) the user clicks on the C2QB button
2) the OAUTH popup window appears
3) the user authorizes access to QB account
4) the authorization works
but...
the popup does not close.  My application runs in the popup browser.  The authorization works. 
I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you please paste your code in the question? With our it, we'll find it tricky to guess what is wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the accessToken(and accessSecret) callback handler redirect to an intermediate page to close the child window and to take the control to the parent page.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.opener.location = '<%=APP_URL%>/home.htm';
    window.close();
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what I was doing wrong.  I was using Server.Transfer to go to new pages in my app instead of Response.Redirect.  This causes the URL in the browser to not update.  Which caused the window.close statement in OauthHandler to not execute.  Thanks for your help.